# RxJS - Map an emitted value to the combined output of multiple Http requests

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular2-observables

I have something like this:

```ts
// getNums returns of Obsevable<number[]>
nums : Observable<number[]> = getNums();

// requestNum is a server call that takes a number and returns Observable<number>
serverNums : Observable<Observable<number>[]> = x.pipe(
    map(num_array => num_array.map(n => requestNum(n)))
);

// Part of an external API that I don't own.
function requestNum(num : number) : Observable<number> {
  // make a server call
}
```

The problem is that `serverNums` is of type `Observable<Observable<number>[]>`.
I need `serverNums` to be `Observable<number[]>` so I can do

```ts
this.result = combineLatest(nums, serverNums).pipe(
    [nums : number[], serverNums : number[]] => {
      for (i=0; i<nums.length; i++) {
        console.log(nums[i], serverNums[i]);
      }
    }
);
```

because `this.result` must be instantiated in my constructor as type `Observable<Result[]>` rather than set in subscribe.

So I can't do `subscribe(() => {this.result = result})`.

Comment: try switchMap/mergeMap etc.

Comment: what do you want ot happen if one of your http requests fails?

Answer (score 1):

Use [forkJoin](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/forkJoin) to execute and combine all your http request and [mergeMap](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/mergeMap) the array emitted from your source to the Observable returned by `forkJoin`.

```js
import { forkJoin } from 'rxjs'; 
import { mergeMap } from 'rxjs/operators';

serverNums : Observable<number[]> = x.pipe(
    mergeMap(num_array => forkJoin(num_array.map(n => requestNum(n))))
);
```

`forkJoin` will combine the last (and only) emitted values from all your http requests into an array after all of them completed. Note that `requestNum` has to complete after emitting a value for `forkJoin` to work. 
(Http request by the Angular `HttpClient` complete after they emit a value)

Depending on your Observable `x` and the desired behaviour you could use [switchMap](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/switchMap) instead of `mergeMap`.

Answer (score 0):

You did not explain what is the structure of Data interface, so I can assume that from the array:

```
[1,2,3]
```

you wish to create the object :

```
{1:1, 2:2, 3:3}.
```

*(if you post your Data interface I will update the answer accordingly).*

---

To create an object from an array you can use [reduce](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/reduce.html):

```
x.pipe(reduce((pre,curr)=>{pre[curr]=curr; return pre;}, {})
```

The pips starts with an empty object ( {} ) and in each iteration adds the pre[curr] property to this object and sets it to be curr.

- **pre** is the previous value from the last iteration
- **curr** is the current value of the current iteration (1, 2 or 3 in the above example)

EDIT:

What you need is to flatten your `Observable<Observable<number>>` to `Observable<number>`, using [mergeMap](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/mergemap.html) (AKA flatMap) :

```
serverNums : Observable<Observable<number>[]> = x.pipe(
    map(num_array => num_array.map(n => requestNum(n)),
    mergeMap(num=>num)
)
```

this will emit all values of requestNum(n) in a single observable of type Observable.

Comment: My actual code is complex, but I updated my question with a more concrete example that illustrates my use case.